# Every closed subset of $R$ has LUM ( Least-upper-bound ) property?

Tags: real-analysis, analysis

Does every closed subset of $R$ has LUM (Least-upper-bound) property?
I think it's wrong but I can't give a counterexample for it.
I tried $A=[1,3]$ but every subset of $A$ has $sup$. should I let $A= \varnothing $ ?
If it's true, how can I prove it?
Thank you.

Comment: What is a closed subsequence?

Comment: If by $R$ you mean the real number system, it is not a sequence. So a "subsequence of $R$" is a bit misleading.

Comment: To the edited question, what have you tried? There's a very obvious counterexample.

Comment: @DonThousand Sorry, I mean subset. I wrote it wrong.

Comment: Is It empty set? @DonThousand

Comment: Please include your attempts in the question

Comment: @ImanKianian That is close. In some definitions of LUB, the empty set has the property, and in others, it doesn't. There's an even more obvious counterexample I was thinking of, though.

Comment: @DonThousand Could you give me a hint? What should I think about?

Comment: @ImanKianian Is $\mathbb R$ closed?

Comment: @DonThousand $\mathbb R$ in $\mathbb R$ is opened and closed (because in every metric space $X$, $X$ is closed and opened). and $\mathbb R$ has LUM property. So I think It isn't a counterexample. Is it?

Comment: @ImanKianian Ah, my bad, I define the LUB property somewhat differently than you do. The claim is then correct: Every closed subset has the LUB property.

Comment: @DonThousand So, How can I prove it?

Comment: Well, for any bounded subset of $A$, it is also a bounded subset of $\mathbb R$. Thus, $A$ has a supremum in $\mathbb R$. Can you prove this supremum is in $A$?